# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__sprintf

Tags: visual-studio-2015, lnk2001

I'm trying to compile FTDI demo application in VS2015. 
Since the application originally was built in VS2013 and there some changes related to the new version of VS I have several linking errors.

These are errors that I get:

```
    >FTD3XX.lib(FTD2XX.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__sprintf
    >FTD3XX.lib(devcon.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____iob_func
```

Any suggestion how to resolve the problem?

Comment: P.S. When I opened the project for the first time, VS converted the project to a newer 2015 version.

Comment: Make sure everything is getting rebuilt and there are no static libraries being used.

Comment: There is a use of one static library.

Comment: If you are trying to link against a static library built with an older version of Visual Studio, the it is quite likely to fail to link against the VS 2015 compiler which uses the [Universal CRT](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/). Make sure you are rebuilding all the code you are using in static libraries. Note this issue doesn't apply to using DLLs in classic Win32 desktop apps.

Answer (score 1):

Well, thanks to Chuck Walbourn, the problem have been resolved. 
The problem was in static library and accidentally I targeted to a different directory were DLL should be placed.

Thanks!